# ASP.NET: Get a strongly typed reference to a parent ASCX control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control (Dashboard.ascx) which contains a child control (DashboardChild.ascx).

From the child control, I would like to get a strongly typed reference to the parent to set a couple properties on the parent (Dashboard.ascx).

One idea that came to mind is to define a reference in my DashboardChild.ascx and on Page Load assign the parent to the child:

**Dashboard.ascx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DasbhardChild.DashboardParent = this;
}
```

**DashboardChild.ascx**

```
 <%@ Register Src="~/Home/Dashboard.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Dashboard" %>   

// Code Behind
public Dashboard DashboardParent { get; set; }

protected void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DashboardParent.AdditionalInfo = "ABC";
}
```

However, this doesn't work as I get a runtime error: Circular file references are not allowed.

Any other ideas of how to get a strongly typed reference to a parent from a child?

Comment: Asuming DashboardChild has a "Parent" property: `Dashboard temp = (Dashboard)this.Parent;`

Comment: Without using the Register directive (which causes a circular reference error) I cannot use the type Dashboard. I get an error message: The type or namespace name 'Dashboard' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you do not know the type that the parent has, how could you get and store a strong reference to it? Really, it is just basic casting.

Comment: @Christopher I can only get access to the type if I register it with the above directive, and then visual studio recognizes it as a type. However, I get a circular reference exception at runtime. I'm looking for ideas/workarounds.

Comment: Why do you get a Circular Reference? Why not solve said circular reference?

Comment: @Christopher because you can't Register a child in a parent, and then Register a parent in a child. Which is exactly what I was trying to do, and was the only way I was actually able to have Visual Studio pick up "Dashboard" as a type.

Answer (score 1):

Best not to work backwards, up the tree. Remember, when the page renders, the only thing rendered on the page is html.

On the aspx page:

```
Control DashboardChild = null;
bool c = Dashboard.Controls.Contains(DashboardChild); // returns false.
```

The code won't find a control on the page, *only html*, whatever is in the child  control - not the control itself.

Also see first answer here (first paragraph): [Nested User Controls - how to best get a reference to an ancestor control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445282/nested-user-controls-how-to-best-get-a-reference-to-an-ancestor-control)